# jQuery show / hide within same content area without a gap

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a navigation div with a width of 300px. The top level menu should slide to the left upon clicking a link and the corresponding linked div should slide in. I have this working but there is a moment where the content fading out to the left from the top nav menu's area is still visible before the new content slides in.

I'm trying to remove this gap, I've had to add a delay to the code to stop it loading under the top menu and then "jumping" which doesn't look good.

The page can be found here: http://projects.dabbble.com/wordcloud/ - click on a link to see the issue.

The JS for this (after loading jQuery and the jQuery UI plugin) is here: http://projects.dabbble.com/wordcloud/lib/js/wordcloud.js?v=0.7

jQuery isn't a strong point for me, so the code can probably be tidied up quite a but so many thanks for any / all help!

James

Comment: This is a side note, you should probably only have one function instead of 7, within this function you can figure out which link was clicked. This would make it more maintainable in the future, in case you wanted to make changes to the animation, you would only have to change it in once place.

Comment: Isn't the delay caused by the delay( 500 ) calls you've got in your JS?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder This probably should be 1 function, unfortunately jQuery isn't something I'm familiar with and I simply don't know how to make this 1 function. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: @Patrick The delay in the sub menu loading was necessary to stop the new menu appearing under the sliding out top menu then "jumping" up to where it should be. It looked worse like that...

Comment: could you post your code to jsfiddle.net so that it's easier to help?I know that it might take you a while, but providing a fiddle is the best way to ask for help.

Comment: @Nicola I've uploaded the code to JS Fiddle, you can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/rMUZ7/ Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here is a simpler jsfiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/arnley/yJKdj/

Answer (score 0):

Something like for one function, you'd need to add classes to your html markup and a title attribute to each link item so that it knew which div to slide in right: -

```
// Hide Sub Menus on Load
$(".wordcloud-menu").hide();

$(".menu-item").click(function(){

var selectElement = $(this).attr("title");

    $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    // Hide Sub Menus on Load
    $(selectedElement).delay("500").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
    return false;

});
```

Would suggest using animate and CSS overflow hidden. For example;

```
$(selectedElement + ":hidden").show().animate({"right": "+=300px"}, "650");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve,
you should try the following:

To go to a subsection:

- .show() that subsection
- move your #wordcloud-sections to the left by
  300px

To go back to the main section:

- move your #wordcloud-sections to the right by 300px

Does that make sense to you?